# How to calculate difference between two times?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes that allow a user to enter a start time and an end time in this format (h:mm). I want it to return the difference in a label. For example, if a user enters 1:35 in the first textbox and 3:30 in the second textbox and press the 'Calculate' button, it will return the time 1:55.

Any ideas or resources for this? I only want to calculate the hour and minute difference between two textboxes. Date and seconds doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, Not really a duplicate to linked question, The input values are different *(with AM,PM)* and that requires `DateTime` parsing.

Comment: @Habib The underlying problem is the same; there 2 time values, these values need to be parsed then subtracted. This question is only a simpler instance of the other one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both of the textboxes values to [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then you can take their difference using `-`.

```
TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox1.Text); //"1:35"
TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox2.Text); //"3:30"

label.Text = (ts2 - ts1).ToString();         //"1:55:00"
```

Comment: @Habib : Is it possible to get the result like this :  textbox1.Text=4/26/2015 5:39:09 AM AND textBox2.Text= 4/26/2015 5:45:24 AM. I want to get the result 6. (ie, I want to calculate the difference between time(5:39:09 - 5:45:24 ))

Comment: @Reshma, it is possible, Parse the date strings to `DateTime` using `DateTime.Parse` or `ParseExact` and then do the subtraction. There are plenty of example for DateTime parsing and then taking their difference

Answer (score 2):

If you cast the input as `DateTime` objects you can calculate the absolute time between them like so:

```
DateTime.Parse(startDate).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(endDate)).Duration().ToString("hh:mm");
```